# ¿Cómo compruebo la validez de una fecha?

Tags: java

Tengo que comprobar que una fecha introducida en un formulario es válida.

La fecha la tengo separada en año, día y mes. Y no me interesa comprobar fechas anteriores a 1900.

Lo estoy haciendo con este código :

```
public class Fecha
{
    int año;
    int mes; // 1 a 12
    int dia; // 1 a 31
}

static int[] diasMes= {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
/**
 *   Comprueba si la fecha es correcta. Se comprueban solo fechas de 1900 
 * o posteriores.
 * @param fecha La fecha a comprobar.
 * @return true si la fecha es correcta, false en otro caso.
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException si el año es menor que 1900.
 */
boolean validaFecha( Fecha fecha)
{
    if ( fecha.año < 1900 ) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException( 
                "Solo se comprueban fechas del año 1900 o posterior");
    }
    if ( fecha.mes<1 || fecha.mes>12 )
        return false;
    // Para febrero y bisiesto el limite es 29
    if ( fecha.mes==2 && fecha.año%4==0 )
        return fecha.dia>=1 && fecha.dia<=29;
    return fecha.dia>=0 && fecha.dia<=diasMes[fecha.mes-1];
}
```

La clase `Fecha` que uso es algo más complicada, tiene sus setter, getter y otras cosas, pero esos detalles son irrelevantes para esta pregunta. La pregunta es acerca del método `validaFecha`.

¿Es correcta la implementación? ¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo con las librerías standard?

Comment: Los [años bisiestos no son cada 4 años *exactamente*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%C3%B1o_bisiesto)

Comment: Pues si que es complicado el tema. Y encima se estima que para el 3344 podría ser necesario un día 30 de Febrero. Tanto más motivo para querer hacerlo con una librería estandard que ya la ajustarán si hace falta.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> ¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo con las librerías standard?

Dependiendo de la versión de Java que estés usando, tienes acceso a algunas clases que ya están incluídas en el JDK sin requerir una librería externa (archivos JARs adicionales).

- **Desde Java 8**

  Si estás usando Java 8, puedes utilizar la clase [`java.time.LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html)<sup>1</sup> para construir una fecha con el año, mes y día. Es decir:

  ```
  import java.time.LocalDate;
  import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

  public class Main {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
          int year = 2016;                   // año
          int month = 1;                     // mes [1,...,12]
          int dayOfMonth = 1;                // día [1,...,31]

          if (year < 1900) {
              throw new IllegalArgumentException("Año inválido.");
          } 

          LocalDate today = LocalDate.of(year, month, dayOfMonth);
          DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
          System.out.println(formatter.format(today)); // 01/01/2016
      }
  }
  ```

  Si alguno de los valores (año, mes, día) es inválido, el método `LocalDate.of` lanzará `java.time.DateTimeException`.
- **Desde el JDK1.1**

  Si estás usando Java 6/7, puedes utilizar las clases [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) y [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)<sup>2</sup> para construir una fecha con el año, mes y día. Es decir:

  ```
  import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
  import java.util.Calendar;
  import java.util.Date;

  public class Main {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
          int year = 2016;                   // año
          int month = 1;                     // mes [1,...,12]
          int dayOfMonth = 1;                // día [1,...,31]

          if (year < 1900) {
              throw new IllegalArgumentException("Año inválido.");
          }

          Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
          calendar.setLenient(false);
          calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
          calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month - 1); // [0,...,11]
          calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
          Date date = calendar.getTime();
          SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
          System.out.println(sdf.format(date)); // 01/01/2016
      }
  }
  ```

  Se debe especificar `calendar.setLenient(false);` para permitir sólo valores dentro de los rangos correspondientes (año, mes, día). Si alguno de estos valores es inválido, `Calendar` lanzará `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`.

<sub>────────────

1. Puedes ver algunos ejemplos de esta y otras clases en [*Java SE 8 Date and Time*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html).

2. Puedes ver algunos ejemplos en [*Java Date and Calendar examples*](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-date-and-calendar-examples/). También en [*Clase Calendar de Java*](http://chuwiki.chuidiang.org/index.php?title=Clase_Calendar_de_Java).</sub>

Comment: Interesante, aunque creo que le ayudaría más una opción basada en **su código** más que utilizando las librerías del JDK.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza De hecho la segunda pregunta es solucionada con esta respuesta.

Comment: @FranciscoAlvarado en ningún momento dije que no lo fuese ;) solo digo que sería más productivo primero indicar cómo corregir el código presentado en lugar de borrarlo de la faz de la tierra y poner una nueva solución. Imagina cómo te sentirías tú si al código que te ha tomado esfuerzo de crear venga otro programador y lo borre porque tiene otras formas de hacerlo y punto, o por lo menos que lo haga sin explicar por qué. Y usando el JDK hay más maneras que las presentadas arriba.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza +1 también para tu respuesta porque aporta nuevas opciones que ayudan al usuario que hace la pregunta

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Es una mala práctica en cualquier lenguaje validar fechas *"a mano"*, reinventando la rueda de manera por lo general deficiente. Lo correcto es usar las funcionalidades de fecha que te da el lenguaje. Las rutinas de aritmética de fechas y validación de fechas *"a mano"* son la fuente de muchos errores ya que por lo general el enfoque es ingenuo.

Comment: @user1598390 no estoy hablando en ningún momento si es mala prácica o no. Este puede ser un ejercicio para alguien que está aprendiendo a programar, por tanto la solución inicial **debería** ir por el fragmento de código presentado. Luego, presentar otras opciones más robustas ya utilizando las bondades del lenguaje y/o frameworks adicionales. Este es un punto clásico de discusión.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Las clases `Calendar`, `Date` o `LocalDate` no forman parte de ningún framework adicional. Vienen con el lenguaje. Son parte básica del mismo. Parte de la formación de los programadores nuevos tiene que ver con conocer el lenguaje. Nuestro deber como programadores senior es guiar a los novatos por el camino de las buenas prácticas. Es por ello que esta respuesta me parece la más a certada.

Comment: Hola, @LuiggiMendoza ¡Gracias por los comentarios! — Respecto al alcance de mi respuesta, he agregado la aclaración correspondiente. :)

Comment: @user1598390 al parecer no entiendes lo que trato de decir. Mi punto es: el OP tiene una pregunta con **su** código, la respuesta debería estar orientada **en base a sú código primero**, luego mostrar las bondades que ofrece el lenguaje de programación **y/o** (nótese el **Y** porque al parecer no lo leiste en el otro comentario) el uso de otros frameworks adicionales, lo que quiere decir que si el lenguaje ya provee esto, genial, y, adicional a esto, se puede mostrar cómo se puede complementar esto con el uso de algún framework externo.

Comment: @user1598390 Además, en ninguno de mis comentarios indico que esta publicación es incorrecta. Solo recalco que lo mejor siempre es **responder en base al esfuerzo que ya ha hecho el OP**, luego brindar agregados.

Comment: @PaulVargas muchas gracias por tu comprensión :)

Comment: Las respuestas a esta pregunta me han hecho ver que mi esfuerzo iba en la dirección errónea y que lo mejor es que lo descarte todo menos la comprobación del 1900 y lo substituya por la librería estandard. Que es un código más breve, elegante y correcto. Gracias a todos.

Comment: Esta es la mejor respuesta. Pero me parece que cabe añadir lo siguiente: si usamos Java 7 o anterior, sería mejor usar la librería externa [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) y su clase [`LocalDate`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html). Esta librería es la precursora de la `java.time` que se añadió en Java 8.

Answer (score 5):

> ¿Es correcta la implementación?

No. Basado en tu código, yo cambiaría esta parte:

```
if (fecha.mes==2 && fecha.año%4==0)
```

Puesto que [la regla para años bisiestos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%C3%B1o_bisiesto) es (énfasis mía):

> Un año es bisiesto si **es divisible entre 4, a menos que sea divisible entre 100**. Sin embargo, **si un año es divisible entre 100 y además es divisible entre 400, también resulta bisiesto**. Obviamente, esto elimina los años finiseculares (últimos de cada siglo, que ha de terminar en 00) cuyo siglo no es múltiplo de 4.

Esto significa:

- Si el año es múltiplo de 400, es bisiesto.
- Sino, si el año es múltiplo de 4 y no de 100, es bisiesto.

La forma más sencilla para adaptar esto en tu código es:

```
if (fecha.mes==2 && dia==29) {
        return fecha.año % 400 == 0 ||
               (fecha.año % 4 == 0 && fecha.año % 100 != 0);
}
```

Otro error que tienes es en esta parte:

```
return fecha.dia >= 0 ...
```

Que está en la última línea del método. Debería ser `fecha.dia >=1`

---

> ¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo con las librerías standard?

Si quieres utilizar las clases del JDK, además de las opciones indicadas por @PaulVargas, puedes utilizar [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), disponible en cualquier versión de Java (desde 1.5 que recuerde). Acá el código:

```
boolean validaFecha( Fecha fecha) {
    if ( fecha.año < 1900 ) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException( 
        "Solo se comprueban fechas del año 1900 o posterior");
    }
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String fechaAValidar = String.format("%d-%d-%d", fecha.año, fecha.mes, fecha.dia);
    boolean result = true;
    try {
        sdf.parse(fechaAValidar);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        //la excepción es silenciosa
        result = false;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Creo que hay que revisar la parte de código tras "La forma más sencilla para adaptar esto en tu código es:". Si leo bien ese código acepta solo los días 29 de febrero (que cumplan la condición de bisiesto) y rechaza todos los otras días de febrero. Pero +1 por la descripción precisa de bisiesto y las librerias de JDK.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos el resto del código sigue así: `return fecha.dia>=0 && fecha.dia<=diasMes[fecha.mes-1];` lo cual cubre que si no es un año bisiesto y es febrero,el día debe estar entre 0 (?) y 28.

Comment: Pero si fecha.mes==2 se entra en el return que has puesto tu. Y si el dia no es 29 devuelve siempre false. Pienso que el código tendría que ser `if (fecha.mes==2 && fecha.dia==29) { return fecha.año%400 || (fecha.año%4==0 && fecha.año%100!=0); }` . Y sí, lo de >=0 lo tengo mal, debiera ser >=1; otro fallo que tengo.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos editado!

Comment: No se si me explico bien. Como estaba tu código si es febrero entra en ese `if` y da devuelve `false` si el día no es 29; que no sería correcto. He sugerido una edición.